# Simulate Android Galaxy S6 Joystick With Mac

Tags: android, bluetooth

I recently acquired one of these Samsung Gear VR headsets in order to start experimenting with this technology and hopefully develop something too:

[image: gear vr]

But to my surprise, you need a gamepad for almost every game, which is also very unavailable. Even in the samsung official site, it says it doesn't have information about retails that sell it (the Samsung Gamepad):

[image]

Some pages suggest using other controllers that work also, such as the Moga Hero Power:

[image]

But these are not easily available to me, and every controller I get will take weeks to get here.

In the meanwhile, I'd like to attempt to connect to the device using my computer, and hopefully be able to simulate a joystick. Can this be done over wifi or bluetooth? How about from another Android?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. You may be able to use an OTG adapter to plug a regular keyboard straight in. I don't know if the exterior USB port on the Gear VR supports USB Host passthrough though.
2. You can connect to the device wirelessly over adb and then send key events from your terminal (on desktop). Let me know if you'd like more detail about that. It won't be super responsive, but better than nothing.